# How to select a row from a datatable by comparing trimmed data?

Tags: asp.net, string, datatable

```
filteredrows = Server_Tables[i].Select("Servername='" + searchtext + "'");
```

The code above compares the data without trimming and selects matched rows.

So how to select rows with trimming?

Comment: what do you mean by triming?

Comment: assume "venkat   " is the servername in datatable. if i give "venkat" in searchtext, it is not selecting the row even though it is matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
filteredrows = Server_Tables[i].Select("TRIM(Servername) ='" + searchtext.Trim() + "'");
```

[Filter expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) used in Datatable.Select supports `TRIM` function. I've also added [Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?) to your entered values since spaces are possible there as well.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) please mark the solution as answer if it was useful

Answer (score 0):

Do you need following;

```
filteredrows = Server_Tables[i].Select("Trim(Servername)='%" + searchtext.Trim() + "%'");
```

Comment: No i have trimmed searchtext.. But Server_Tables contains untrimmed data. so thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Trim **searchtext** variable;

```
filteredrows = Server_Tables[i].Select("TRIM(Servername)='%" + searchTerm + "%'");
```

To trim **row values** while retrieving with select method you can use;

```
filteredrows = Server_Tables[i].Select("Servername='%" + searchTerm.Trim() + "%'");
```